# How do I roll in Warframe?

Tags: warframe

On [this page](https://warframe.com/game/quickstart#controls), on the gamepad control section it says:

> 2: You can sprint by holding down the left joystick. If you tap it, your character will perform a roll.

On the Keyboard Controls section, there is no trace of rolling. IS there a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You roll by simply tapping the sprint button once (<kbd>shift</kbd> by default).

Comment: After.. ahem.. extensive testing and erm.. ponderous deliberation I have decided to accept this answer..

Answer (score 1):

You press the run button (<kbd>shift</kbd> by default) twice.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be testing this tonight or tomorrow during lunch break!

Comment: I've always managed to roll just tapping Shift.

Comment: Twice works, too, but once is how it's usually done.